# d3 v5 scaleThreshold not accepting array of string colors on range?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

this is my code:

```
var legendThreshold = d3
      .scaleThreshold()
      .domain(
        (function(min, max, count) {
          var array = [];
          var step = (max - min) / count;
          var base = min;
          for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            array.push(base + i * step);
          }
          return array;
        })(minTemp, maxTemp, legendColors.length)
      )
      .range(["red", "white", "green"]);
```

I am getting error on range saying:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'readonly number[]'

but if you look on the sample in this [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#_threshold) i believe my code should be correct. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are working with TypeScript.

You might need to provide the generics for `d3.scaleThreshold()` in order for it to accept strings.

As mentioned on the [DefinitelyTyped TypeScript type definitions for D3.js](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/index.d.ts#L1435),

> - Constructs a new threshold scale. The domain and range must be set corresponding to the type of the corresponding generic.
>
>   - The first generic corresponds to the data type of domain values.
>   - The second generic corresponds to the data type of range values.

Since you are using strings for both `domain` and `range`,  we can specify both types as `string`.

```
d3.scaleThreshold<string, string>().domain().range()
```

[Reference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/index.d.ts#L1374)

Comment: i have just tried that but i am still getting error, on the <string> saying: 'No overload expects 1 type arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 0 or 2 type arguments.'

Comment: @iamgpbaculio Sorry, it should be `<string, string>` instead. The first generic corresponds to the data type of domain values, and the second generic corresponds to the data type of range values. Your range returns strings, but can I double check if your domain returns strings or numbers?